# How to build a program using boost::asio::spawn

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, c++17, spawn

How I can to build a program that uses boost lib?

I can't build an example of use `boost::asio:spawn`.

- G++ version: 7.3
- Boost Lib version: 1.69

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>

int main ()
{
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;

  // Spawn coroutine.
  boost::asio::spawn(io_service,
    [&io_service](boost::asio::yield_context yield_context) {
      // Add more 'work' to the io_service.
      io_service.post([] {
        std::cout << "Other work" << std::endl;
      });

      // Wait on a timer within the coroutine.
      boost::asio::deadline_timer timer(io_service);
      timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
      std::cout << "Start wait" << std::endl;
      timer.async_wait(yield_context);
      std::cout << "Woke up" << std::endl;
    });

  io_service.run();
}
```

Error:

```
boost::asio::experimental::co_spawn has not been declared
```

Comment: I'm trying to build this lib: -lboost_coroutine -lboost_system

Comment: I [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.
But you still may need to add further information for your question to become fully solvable.

Comment: Added C++ tag for visibility, per request on the c++17 tag wiki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to reproduce your issue, but cannot (using the same versions your report).

Also see it [Live On Wandbox (GCC7.3/boost1.69)](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bnJCot151SFXo7S1).

Here's what I use to build:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -pthread -I ~/custom/boost_1_69_0/ -L ~/custom/boost_1_69_0/stage/lib/ test.cpp -lboost_{thread,context,coroutine,system} -DBOOST_COROUTINES_NO_DEPRECATION_WARNING
```

That's a bash oneliner for:

> `g++ -std=c++11 -pthread \
>        -I /home/sehe/custom/boost_1_69_0/ \
>        -L /home/sehe/custom/boost_1_69_0/stage/lib/ \
>        test.cpp \
>        -lboost_thread \
>        -lboost_context \
>        -lboost_coroutine \
>        -lboost_system \
>        -DBOOST_COROUTINES_NO_DEPRECATION_WARNING`

Comment: Also see it [Live On Wandbox (GCC7.3/boost1.69)](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bnJCot151SFXo7S1)

Comment: Do You know how to or where I should add DBOOST_COROUTINES_NO_DEPRECATION_WARNING flag in eclipse?

Comment: You the `BOOST_COROUTINES_NO_DEPRECATION_WARNING` define, or the `-DBOOST_COROUTINES_NO_DEPRECATION_WARNING` commandline parameter to define it. You can just put it in the code. Otherwise, google is your friend: https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fcdt_u_prop_general_sd_entries.htm (the first hit on "eclipse add compiler defines")

Comment: Welcome to [SO]. Please also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work